# Search has no attribute teaser

Tags: python, regex, json, python-3.x

I am trying to access `teaser`. I tried many different things, such as "print(search.teaser)," do you guys know what I have to do to access `teaser`?

```
import re
import json
import requests


class search:
    def run():

        data = requests.get("http://boards.4chan.org/g/catalog").text
        match = re.match(".*var catalog = (?P<catalog>\{.*\});.*", data)

        if not match:
            print("Couldn't scrape catalog")
            exit(1)

        catalog = json.loads(match.group('catalog'))

        running = True
        while running:

                try:
                     filtertext = ("tox")
                     for number, thread in catalog['threads'].items():
                        sub, teaser = thread['sub'], thread['teaser']
                        if filtertext in sub.lower() or filtertext in teaser.lower():

                        return(teaser)
                        running = False


            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                running = False


print(search.teaser)
```

Comment: where do you think teaser comes from? It should be `def run(self):` but you don't need a class at all really.

Comment: You never assign `self.teaser`, it's just a local variable inside `search.run`. I suggest you look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html, or just use a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do but I think  you want to call the method `run`.
Your `Search` class has no `attribute` `teaser`, you define teaser in your `run` method as a variable that you return in that method:

```
class Search:
    def run(self): # need the self parameter

        data = requests.get("http://boards.4chan.org/g/catalog").text
        match = re.match(".*var catalog = (?P<catalog>\{.*\});.*", data)

        if not match:
            print("Couldn't scrape catalog")
            exit(1)  
        catalog = json.loads(match.group('catalog'))   
        running = True
        while running:    
            try:
                filtertext = ("tox")
                for number, thread in catalog['threads'].items():
                    sub, teaser = thread['sub'], thread['teaser']
                    if filtertext in sub.lower() or filtertext in teaser.lower():
                        return teaser  # return the value of the variable teaser defined above
                running = False    
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                running = False


s = Search() # create instance
print (s.run()) # call run method
```

Which outputs:

```
 Tox is a secure, distributed multimedia messenger aimed at simplifying encrypted communications by means of simple interfaces, no registration, and a wide array of supported platforms. --- Venom now has apt-get install-ability --- wget https://repo.tox.im/tox-apt.sh &amp;&amp; sudo chmod +x ./tox-apt.sh &amp;&amp; ./tox-apt.sh then, apt-get install venom You can update venom through apt-get everytime there is a new successful build for Venom. Clients such as uTox and qTox are in the works for an apt repository, as they currently are not packaged. Venom already ships as .deb, and thus is already ready to ship. https://tox.im https://wiki.tox.im https://github.com/Tox https://github.com/irungentoo/toxcore Want to Groupchat? Add syncbot@toxme.se on your favorite Tox application.
```

An example of using attributes:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "" # attribute
        self.age = "" # attribute
f = Foo()
f.name = "Foobar" # access attribute and set to "Foobar"
f.age = 34   # access attribute and set to 34
print(f.name,f.age) # print updated attribtue values
Foobar 34
```